# How to make transparent all the white areas of an image

Tags: image-processing, opacity

Let's take a sample image

[image]

Now I want to make transparent all the white areas of the image, so as to be able to copy/paste it above text

[image]

After the copy/paste only the color parts (non-white) of the figure should be covering the text.

I use version 9.0 of Mathematica.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLncI.png"]`, `Export["transparent.png", SetAlphaChannel[img, 1 - ColorSeparate[img][[1]]]]` seems to work. But it's not going to be generalizable to more complex images... Although, having just seen @C.E.'s answer, `RemoveBackground` seems like the right way to go in this case.

Comment: @aardvark2012 When I run your code I get the following error message `SetAlphaChannel::invalpha: Expecting an image or a number between 0 and 1 for the alpha channel specification instead of 1`

Comment: What does `1 - ColorSeparate[img][[1]]` give you? It gives me an image that I use as a mask... albeit a pretty hacky one.

Comment: @aardvark2012 When I run `1 - ColorSeparate[img][[1]]` I get 1 - the image in black and white.

Comment: So `SetAlphaChannel` _should_ be using that image as the mask... no idea what's going on there and why the error is appearing (it doesn't for me). But `RemoveBackground` seems to be working for you now, so I'd stick with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Use `RemoveBackground[img, {"Background", White}]`
2. Use `SetAlphaChannel` together with a mask

How to generate the mask would depend on the image. `Binarize` works in this case.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific, providing an example?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Yes, if you are more specific about what you don't understand. A general question will get a general answer, whereas a very specific question will get a very specific answer.

Comment: When I use `RemoveBackground[img, {"Background", White}]` the exported JPEG image is not transparent,

Comment: Afaik, JPEGs don't support transparency. Try as PNG?

Comment: @aardvark2012 Yes, you are absolutely right! The PNG is indeed transparent.